# Can't Save "Is a Tomcat Project" setting in Eclipse Project Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, mongrel

I have a Spring MVC project that I've been deploying to Tomcat (installed both locally and on a server).  I'm using Eclipse Indigo as my IDE.  To deploy, I had been right clicking and choosing "run on server", which would run fine on localhost.  For deploying a WAR to the actual server, I had been right clicking on Project, selecting Export, and going through the wizard to deploy a WAR file.

My Eclipse/Java is rusty, but I did remember that when I used it a couple of years back, I was using the Sysdeo plugin for Tomcat that would give me an option for Deploy to War right from the right click context.  So, I poked around and found "Mongrel", which I installed.  With that in place, I went to Mongrel under preferences, and set up my Tomcat version, so that I can click the little start/stop Tomcat icons and start/stop the server.  This was successful.

What I can't now do for the life of me is, in Project Properties->Tomcat, choose "Is a Tomcat Project".  I check the checkbox and then click Apply and/or OK to dismiss the window, and when I open it again, my setting is not recorded.  I have tried checking the box and adding other options (like context name, path for a WAR file export, root sub-directory, and activating dev loader), but nothing I do "sticks".

Can someone tell me what I'm missing, or at least point me in the right direction?  I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you mean when next time you go to properties, you are not getting the Is Tomcat project checkbox selected ?

Comment: @programmer_1 Yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm not using Mongrel... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this may be a late answer, but as I had the same issue today, I figure I could post my findings here.

I had the exact same problem as yours when I installed mongrel from the eclipse marcket place.
The solution for me was to uninstall mongrel, delete the plugin folder in the plugin directory of eclipse and then get the plugin from [the project page on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mongrel/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I still haven't figured this out, so I'll give it a try when I get home and give you the check if it works.  :)

Comment: +1! Thanks! I was having the same problem and this solved! Just an advice for all, put your downloaded plugin in the 'eclipse/dropins' folder. Don't use 'eclipse/plugins' because your plugin will get lost between the others. (indigo+ only)